# Change progress indicator design - Custom Journey Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, lightning-design-system, custom-activity

We are currently developing a multi step Custom Activity within Marketing Cloud.
The UI for the steps is quite old fashioned, as you can see from the picture bellow:

[image]

There is a newer design within Salesforce lightning design system and our progression indicator should look like this:
[image]

or https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/progress-indicator/#In-a-Modal

Is there any way to this? Either within the configuration json file for my custom activity or some other alternative?
My current code looks like this:

```
"wizardSteps": [
    {
      "key": "step1",
      "label": "Welcome"
    },
    {
      "key": "step2",
      "label": "Mapping"
    },
    {
      "key": "step3",
      "label": "Finished"
    }
  ],
  "userInterfaces": {
    "configInspector": {
      "size": "medium"
    }
  },
```

Thanks in advance.
Kind regards